# Android - Websettings settextsize, how to add other values other than the 5 presets

Tags: android

In my application I am using a webview, and in order to increase/decrease text size, I am using WebSettings().setTextSize method, but, this method is limited to 5 predefined enum sizes only (SMALLEST, SMALLER, NORMAL, LARGER,LARGEST). I know I can use WebSettings().setTextZoom(int), but my application is available for API Level 8 and above, and this method was introduced in API Level 14.

My question is: Is there any way to add other sizes to webSettings().setTextSize? maybe by extending textSize enum, or define other sizes?

BTW:
WebSettings.setDefaultFontSize(int size) is not working, probably because the webpages i use contains a big CSS file...

Answer (score 0):

You can inject css code into your application on pageloadfinished and change the text size with that.

Example to change background color to gradient with css inject:

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    //styling

    webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +  
        "document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.background = '-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#143b8a), to(#266af3))'; " + 
        "})()");  
}
```